# How effective has the war on poverty been at eliminating poverty?

Tags: united-states, poverty

[Lyndon Johnson](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=26787#axzz1Zj5CoCZC) declared a war on poverty in his 1964 State of the Union address.

> Let this session of Congress be known as the session which did more for civil rights than the last hundred sessions combined; as the session which enacted the most far-reaching tax cut of our time; **as the session which declared all-out war on human poverty and unemployment in these United States**; as the session which finally recognized the health needs of all our older citizens; [...]

The [War on Poverty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Poverty#Major_initiatives) include several social programs

> - [Social Security Act 1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_Amendments_of_1965) (Created Medicare and Medicaid) – July 19, 1965
> - [Food Stamp Act of 1964](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_Stamp_Act_of_1964)- August 31, 1964[3]
> - The [Economic Opportunity Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Economic_Opportunity_Act_of_1964) of 1964 which created the Community Action Program, Job Corps and Volunteers in Service to America (VISTA), centerpiece of the "war on poverty" – August 20, 1964
> - [Elementary and Secondary Education Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_and_Secondary_Education_Act) - April 11, 1965

We are coming up on the 50th year of LBJ's War on Poverty, **How effective has the war on poverty been at eliminating poverty?** What percentage of the population is living in poverty today as compared to 1963, after LBJ's war on poverty?

Answer (score 4):

[This page from Politifact.com](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2011/jul/29/bill-oreilly/bill-oreilly-says-poverty-hasnt-budged-1965-despit/) goes over a lot of the relevant data. Since 1965, total poverty rates have been reduced from 17.3% to 14.3%. However (as the other answer shows as well), these rates are somewhat dependent on the economy. Before the recession, poverty rates were even lower, at 12.5%.

For some groups in particular, poverty rates have dropped dramatically. 30% of the elderly were poor in 1965. Now, only 13.2% are. Poverty rates for African Americans have also dropped similarly.

In general, social welfare programs [tend to reduce poverty](http://www.lisdatacenter.org/wps/liswps/188.pdf). America has eliminated [26.4% of its poverty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare%27s_effect_on_poverty#Table_of_welfare_effect_on_poverty_reduction) from 1967 to 2002 through the use of social welfare programs, and many other countries managed to reduce poverty levels even more during that period.

Answer (score 2):

The poverty rate has fluctuated along with the economy, but is approximately the same now as it was in 1965.

[image: Chart showing US poverty rates from 1959 to 2011]

Comment: From the graph, it appears that the poverty rate was about 19-20% in 1963, before the LBJ legislation. Does this mean that a 4% improvement was reached?